# meaning : I have a job for you

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

In a movie; Johnwick. I wondered what a word means after listening to conversation.

> A : What brings you here?
> B : I have a job for you.

I want to know the exact meaning of "have", I'm not sure whether it means "to own" or " to hold" or "to organize" or "to bring". Even though I have often heard the expression;I have a job for you. I don't know the exact meaning. I want to know the exact meaning.

Answer (score 4):

It is "own or possess" in an extended sense.  Not in the sense of owning a car, but indicating that something exists in relation to the speaker.

The word "have" indicates a wide range of types of possession:

> I have a car (simply owning)

> I have a brother (I don't *own* my brother... but he exists)

> I have an idea  (in my head)

> I have a suggestion (there is something that I want to say)

Only the first of these indicates legal ownership.  But the word "have" can be used correctly in all of them.

> I have a job for you.

Indicates that the task exists in relation to the speaker. In particular, the speaker is able to assign that task to the other person.

With very common words like "have" there is a very wide range of meanings, and it won't simply translate into a single word in another language.